# How to use font awesome icons in swift?

Tags: swift, svg, icons, glyphicons

I use this code but icon is no displayed and it shows me like this

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/hPEPs.png]

```
medicalpacakgesbutton.setTitle("\u{f0c3}", for: .normal)
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to use Font Awesome in your app is [FontAwesome.Swift](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift)

Example for a button icon:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 30)
button.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .coffee), for: .normal)
```

Or for a tab bar icon:

```
let image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .coffee, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
viewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Coffee", image: image, tag: 1)
```

Comment: Anyone know it this should work with tvOS? I have installed FontAwesome.Swift (using Cocoapods) but the Font Awesome members are not found on String/UIFont.

Comment: @sundance thank for your sulotion  ,  how can we use  this icon in collection View

Comment: fyi - FontAwesome.Swift is designed for the free icons only. You can dig through the issues to hack it for pro icons, but it's all for older versions of font awesome. So if you're on v6+ where FA renamed everything, good luck

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found that I set the wrong font name for the label. Although the file name was `fa-solid-900.ttf`, it all worked only after I changed the name of the font for the label to the following

```
label.font = UIFont.init(name: "FontAwesome5Free-Solid", size: 32)
```

You can see all fonts available for the application by performing

```
func printAllFonts() {
    UIFont.familyNames.forEach({ familyName in
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print(familyName, fontNames)
    })
}
```